# how can I configure updates in my CMS like wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have a CMS built in core PHP. Till now, if a new version is released, it is downloaded to client machine in zipped form. And then client has to manually unzip the folder and copy that to required location. Because there is no way to download zip file to required location. 
I want that CMS should be updated in the background like-wordpress. 
In other words, I want that new version can replace old version.

how can i do this?

Comment: Are you sur to do this ? I don't develop on WordPress but I've heard that some updates break some plugins. Your client would be a little angry if his website is broken without reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things required to allow for this:

1. You must separate 'core' files from other files, such as extensions, plugins, themes, assets, uploads, etc.
2. The update will only ever update core files, nothing else.
3. You must never change the core files, as your changes will be deleted.  If you need to change these files you must extend them, or in the case of WordPress and other systems use hooks and events to ensure the same outcome can be reached without needing to touch these sensitive files.

The update script itself can be relatively straightforward.  It doesn't do anything other than what your manual update would do - it simply downloads a zip to your server and extracts it in the appropriate place, and then runs any database migrations required.